# whiteness vs Uncorrelatedness

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, independent-component-analysis

While studying ICA in the book by Aapo Hyvarinen I found the following scentence:

"A slightly stronger property than uncorrelatedness is whiteness. Whiteness of a
zero-mean random vector, say y, means that its components are uncorrelated and
their variances equal unity."

Why is this? Is thare a intuitive interpretation of why unit-variance cause whiteness to be stronger than uncorrelatedness beyond making calculations simpler?

Comment: As stated, whiteness is a [logically stronger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53708/precise-definition-of-weaker-and-stronger) assumption than uncorrelatedness in the sense that whiteness *implies* uncorrelatedness, but not vice versa.

Comment: Hi: uncorrelated means that the process, $X_t$,  is such that the $X_t$ is not linearly related to $X_{t-1}$. OTOH, whiteness means that the process, $Y_t$, is such that $Y_t$ is not related to $Y_{t-1}$. Note that white noise is the derivative of brownian motion so, practically speaking, it doesn't exist. .It's more of a theoretical construct.